# Cross validation overfitting?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

When i print scores, i get `0.90` Accuracy, and when i print CrossValScore i get:
`[0.99382716  0.99382716  0.99689441  0.99689441  0.99689441]` that looks like it's testing on data it have already seen, and i wanted it to test model on unseen data. But i dont know where exactly i made mistake.
In addition, when i change max_features parameter to whichever number, result is i still get the same results in scores and CrossValScore.

```
#some preprocessing here..
#saving preprocessed traain and test data

traindata = ast.literal_eval(open('pretprocesirano.txt').read())
testdata = ast.literal_eval(open('pretprocesiranoTEST.py').read())

label_train=np.array(label_train)
label_test=np.array(label_test)

vectorizer= CountVectorizer(tokenizer=lambda x:x.split())
traindataCV=vectorizer.fit_transform(traindata)

wordlist=vectorizer.vocabulary_
SavedVectorizer = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=wordlist)
testdataCV=SavedVectorizer.transform(testdata)

clf = MultinomialNB()
clf.fit(traindataCV, label_train) 

scores=clf.score(testdataCV,label_test)

CrossValScore = cross_val_score(clf, traindataCV, label_train, cv=5)
```

Comment: This makes sense to me.  Your out-of-fold accuracy in cross-validation is 0.99, and your accuracy on a test set is 0.90.  What's the question?

Comment: I use 4 folds to train and 1 fold to test, and get accuracy 0.99, that is too high, isn't it?

Comment: Not if you have good predictors.  You need to use your subject matter knowledge to determine whether it's just an easy problem or whether there is some sort of "cheating" (aka. "leakage" going on).

Comment: The latter is when you have accidentally included something that has a peek at the outcome -- for example if you sorted by outcome and then accidentally left row number in the predictor set

Comment: Well all i did before this peace of code was preprocessing train and test data the same way, using the same function, and writing it to the files. So the problem must be in these lines.

Comment: why do you do the cross validation process on test data? you are aware that you train 5 classifiers on (different) 4/5 of test data which you evaluate on the left out 1/5 of the test data?

Comment: Man, you are right, i didn't pay attention to that, i just passed the same args as in clf.score, not thinking to much what i am doing.

Comment: @stefan something is confusing me. Now i solved the problem but, this happens: Accuracy with  scores is 0.85, and accuracy with CrossValScore is 0.92 no matter how many folds i use. If i use 2 or 10 folds, accuracy is the same. I suppose it shouldn't be like that.

Comment: numbers sound more reasonable than before. maybe your split traindata/testdata is not exactly random.